# PHP not outputting any data but 0

Tags: php, output

I am sorry for posting this, but PHP is not throwing any errors so I have no idea what is wrong. My code for some reason should work, the stuff needed is all there, yet instead of redirecting when action is not set, it echo's a 0. Then the other stuff does not work.
Can you please help me fix the problem.

```
<?php
include ("inc/config.php");

include ("inc/function.php");

if (is_null($_GET["action"]))
    {
    /*echo '<script>var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?action=login,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.parent.body.innerHTML = response;</script>';*/
    echo '<script> window.location.assign("index.php?action=login")';
    }
elseif (isset($_GET["action"]))
    {
    $acceptableInputs = scandir("inc/html");
    $alreadyThere = scandir("/tmp");
    if (in_array($_GET["action"] + ".html", $acceptableInputs) and !in_array($_GET["action"] + ".php", $alreadyThere))
        {
        $html = file_get_contents($_GET["action"]);
        $fh = fopen("tmp/" + $_GET["action"] + ".php", "w");
        if (in_array($_GET["action"] + ".php", $acceptableInputs))
            {
            fwrite($fh, "include('inc/html/" + $_GET["action"] + ".php')");
            }

        fwrite($fh, $html);
        fclose($fh);
        echo '<script>var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","tmp/' + $_GET['action'] + '.php,true);
xmlhttp.send();
var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.parent.body.innerHTML = response;</script>';
        }
    elseif (in_array($_GET["action"] + ".php", $alreadyThere))
        {
        $files = glob('temp/*');
        foreach($files as $file)
            {
            if (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<script>$('body')" + '.load("error.php")</script>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should place some comments on where it's supposed to enter and where it's entering now.

Comment: ??? Please elaborate on this, what do you mean.
The code is mainly the first part. But the other part is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing is_null and isset. Maybe what you meant is

```
if (!isset($_GET["action"] || is_null($_GET["action"]))
    {
...
    }
else ( )
```

Comment: I thought they were the same? If not what is the difference between them.

Comment: pretty well explained here http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/ complete with nice table of results.

Comment: Thanks, but could you help me with the fact it is not creating any temporary documents even though there is a html document in "inc/html" named login.html

Comment: If $action is unset, if(is_null) is FALSE (since it's not explicitly null), and else if(isset($action)) is false, so neither branch runs!

Comment: I meant if I did set action to "login".

Comment: That would be a separate question, and you'd need to post different code. Most likely one of your conditions `if (in_array($_GET["action"] + ".php", $acceptableInputs))` or the other `elseif (in_array($_GET["action"] + ".php", $alreadyThere))` or both are false, but you didn't share `$acceptableInputs` or `$alreadyThere`.

Comment: acceptable inputs are: login.html and the $alreadyThere variable is null or has nothing inside it yet. And even thought it tests true, and attempts to write the files nothing is ever done and it just echos 0.

Comment: as I said, this should be a separate question by all rights as I answered the first. However, if I understand it right, $acceptableInputs is an array containing 1 item "login.html" and action + ".php" is "login.php" so the if() check fails. Also it needs to be $_GET["action"].".html" not `+` as + adds numeric values!